# Issue with batch script when we pass parameter quoted with " (double inverted comma)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have written below scripts which will ask user to input password as parameter
if I enter password `"Hello&123"` it fails but it is working for other case like `!Hello&123>` please suggest some good approach to overcome this situation.

### TestScript1.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter password:' -AsSecureString ; ^
      $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if "%password%" == "" @echo password cannot be empty & goto DIE
TestScript2.bat.bat testuser "192.168.1.1" "%password%"
endlocal

:DIE
exit /b 1
```

### TestScript2.bat

```
@echo off

echo n | psftp %1@%2 -pw %3 -b Test3.bat >> TestLog.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion when you try to expand the variable.
Delayed expansion is always safe for any content.
But with delayed expansion there are problems with exclamation marks and carets.
That's why you should enabled it after the `set "password=%%p"`.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter password:' -AsSecureString ; ^
      $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
            $str=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR); ^
            Write-host('#'+$str)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "password=%%p"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "password=!password:*#=!"
if not defined password (

    echo password cannot be empty
    goto :DIE
)
echo It works: pwd=!password!
TestScript2.bat testuser "192.168.1.1" "!password!"
```

But you will get the next problem with TestScript2.bat, as the expansion itself is safe, but you can't transfer an arbitrary password to a function or batch file by value (it's really impossible).

So you should transfer it by ref instead by value.

```
TestScript2.bat testuser "192.168.1.1" password
```

And use it in TestScript2.bat again with `!%~3!`

But to call the psftp command with the password causes again the problem with arbitrary values.
You need to escape the content to a safe format, in this case you have to regard the rules of psftp.
I tested, psftp replaces `\""` to `"`.

**TestScript2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "password=!%~3!"
set "password=!password:"=\""!"
... more replace rules
echo n | psftp %1@%2 -pw "!password!" -b Test3.bat >> TestLog.log 2>&1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it failed for password "Hello&123" in this password we have three special characters two " and one &

Comment: do we need to add setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion in other script also ??

Comment: Yes and No, it inherits the state from `TestScript1.bat`, but to write a *good* script you should enable it explictly. But even this will not work, as it will still fail at the `psftp -pw !%3!` part, as there you get again the problem that arbitrary content can not be transfered by value

Comment: yes exactly I am facing the same issue any idea how to overcome this?? it only fails if password has special character "

Comment: Therefore I added the sample `TestScript2.bat`

Comment: Thanks for the solution now it works fine can we put one check for " and do set "password=!password:"=\"!" instead of putting multiple lines as it is causing problem only for " not for other special characters?

Comment: it started failing in case of ;Hello;;123;; and \\Hello\\123\\

Comment: @Aryan I fixed the code when password starts with a semicolon. But you should more text when something doesn't work. Why `\\Hello\\123\\` fails? Which part, what do you get in the variable, what do psftp with the password?

Comment: If i put !%~3! instead of "!password!" in echo n | psftp %1@%2 -pw "!password!" -b Test3.bat >> TestLog.log 2>&1 then it works for password \\Hello\\123\

Comment: could you please elaborate what did you do to fix ; semicolon issue?? I see in above code you have putted set "password=!password:*#=!" it causing the other issue like next time if you dont enter the password it takes previous entered value and never compains about empty passowrd

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
SET Test="Hello"
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS==" %a in ('SET Test') DO @ECHO %~a
```

The %~a strips any quotes off.

Comment: not exactly I want to keep " in password. if we will remove " from password then password will be wrong and it will not be able to connect with host my saying access denied.

Comment: The problem is normally the wrong number of quotes have been added to the string.  You say an unquoted password works but a quoted one doesn't.  So if you use something based on the above you can remove all quotes and then add just on pair.  Also you need to check for " and <> within the password because as Alex K says they screw things up.  Also TestScript2.bat.bat isn't right.

Comment: here problem is password contains " double quotes which is causing the failure if password contains other special character except " double inverted comma then it works fine

Comment: You can't strip quotes from a password, when it's allowed to use them. And `%~` only strips the outer quotes, it will not work when the quotes are in the string itself like `This is "&"& hard`

Comment: Yes you need something else to strip internal quotes, but I get the impression the password is meant to have quotes in

Comment: example password = "HiMatt&Stack" so this password has total 14 characters including two " double quotes

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand and the `>` would both need to be escaped (`!Hello^&123^>`) as they currently are not `%3` is received as `!Hello`.

You can use delayed expansion to get around this:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
TestScript2.bat testuser "192.168.1.1" !password!
```

Comment: this problem came only if password is like "Hello&123" but not for <Hello&123> so if password contains " symbol then it will fail otherwise it will pass